# ActionScript3 & Java encryption / decryption

Tags: java, actionscript-3, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I've got a flash client that communicates with a server. The server-side code is in java. I'd like to be able to encrypt the communication, so it has to be an algorithm that has libraries for both as3 & java.

Speed if more important than the security of the encryption, and ideally it would use asymmetric key encryption.

AES and Blowfish seem like they would work from what I've seen. But both use symmetric keys.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AS3Crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) is a port of the popular Java/C# library [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/).  That works just great.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like opening an HTTPS connection would be the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be working with encrypting data shortly here.  I've chosen to do it using asynchronous RSA encryption.

I'll be using [AS3Crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)'s RSA encryption client-side with the public key.

Server-side I'll be using [JAVA's built-in RSA cryptography](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Key) to decrypt data with the private key.